# Can't display graphs from Google Analytics inside Angular2 app

Tags: angular, google-analytics, dashboard, angular-components

I'm trying to write an Angular2+ component which only displays graphs/datas from Google Analytics (the app doesn't have to be tracked by GA at all, I'm developping a dashboard) but I can't figure out how to do this...

I tried to use the Embed API from Google but it displays nothing.
I tried this : [Google Analytics embed api not working on Angular 2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322623/google-analytics-embed-api-not-working-on-angular-2-app) but it doesn't work and I have not any clue how to do this.